# PHP array_column to return with values only

Tags: php, array-column

Is it possible to get a result from array_column that has values only?

sample array i want to array_column

```
$array = [
   ['name' => ''],
   ['name' => 'John'],
   ['name' => 'Doe']
]
```

when i use array_column this is what i get

```
Array
(
    [0] => 
    [1] => John
    [2] => Doe
)
```

I was going to just use foreach and check each and every value but i was wondering if there is a much easier way to do this

thanks

Comment: Can you show what your expected results are?

Comment: my expected result should be [0 => 'John', 1 => 'Doe']

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you want something like this (to get only the columns which has a value):

```
$array = [
    ['name' => ''],
    ['name' => 'John'],
    ['name' => 'Doe']
];

$result = array_filter(array_column($array, 'name'));
```

The [array_filter](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php) will filter out empty names and you'll get something like this:

```
// print_r($result);

Array
(
    [1] => John
    [2] => Doe
)
```

Also, if you need to reorder the indices then you can use [array_values](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-values.php) like this:

```
$result = array_filter(array_column($array, 'name'));

// If you want to reorder the indices
$result = array_values($result);

// print_r($result);

Array
(
    [0] => John
    [1] => Doe
)
```

Comment: Just be aware that this will filter out empty strings, false, null and 0.

Answer (score 0):

You could also do this to remove both null and empty values:

```
// PHP 7.4+
$result = array_filter(array_column($array, 'name'), fn($val) => !is_null($val) && $val !== '');

// PHP 5.3 and later
$result = array_filter(array_column($array, 'name'), function($val) { return !is_null($val) && $val !== ''; });
```